# Background scene model or image as plane?

Tags: image, scene

I have the 3D model and can render with white background.
However i would like to make the model look like it is in a promo shoot like the attached images, would these be modelled scenes or images as plains or what?
Would there be any good tutorials on this subject that somebody could recommend

[image]

Comment: just use an HDRI background, make a plane under the bike with shadow catcher and render in cycles

Comment: I have tried a few 4k models and it looks really fake so i am a bit stuck TBH

Comment: Yes an HDRI image as background and maybe create the grass with a particle system?